# if exist record in table then update it else insert new

Tags: mysql

I am creating a add_to_cart table.when product add into add_to_cart table I want to increase quantity of product.following are my table add_to_cart

```
{  buyer_id| prod_id| prod_name| qty| prod_barter_val| seller_id
 '3', '5', 'AC', '1', '150000', '5'
'3', '17', 'UPS & Inverts', '1', '111111', '17'
'3', '6', 'water park', '221', '100000', '6'
'3', '1', 'rooms', '1654', '55000', '1'
'3', '4', 'Sticking material', '1', '50,000', '4'
'3', '5', 'AC', '16', '1,50,000', '5'  }
```

IN above table i'm ordering 1 AC after that i want to 16 more ac so increase only quantity but here add one more row for AC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace command in mysql

```
replace into add_to_cart(coloum_name) values(here our data);
```

But you should use update command for all that stuff

```
update add_to_cart set qty=16+qty where prod_id=5
```

Comment: when we are doing online shopping.suppose we purchase 1 shirt and add it into add to cart but after some time we think purchase one more same shirt then increase the quantity.same as like i want the output through query.

Comment: my project is online shopping that is why I want this query.

Answer (score 0):

Use update query instead of insert query. There just update your qty.

Comment: can you give me the query